# Looking for a manhwa/manhua where mc had strong regeneration

Tags: story-identification, manga

I no longer remember if it was a manhwa or a manhua but it was colorful. I think the MC had a strong regenerative ability which had a red and black thing coming out each time it regenerated. The story also had others with abilities, but that's all I remember.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

Comment: It was about 2 years ago I think and I just read it at a random manga website.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.